# Simple chat with JMS

Tags: java, jms

I'm making a simple chat application with JMS, but my code is not working and I don't know why. This is my code and I use with JBoss so I open pub and I write this and when I click start the Eclipse give me this error message:

```
<pre>
Topic or username missingjava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at chat.pub.main(pub.java:105)
</pre>

and this is the code, what is the problem?

    package chat;

    import javax.jms.*;
    import javax.naming.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.Properties;

    public class pub implements javax.jms.MessageListener{
        private TopicSession pubSession;
        private TopicSession subSession;
        private TopicPublisher publisher;
        private TopicConnection connection;
        private String username;

        /* Constructor. Establish JMS publisher and subscriber */
        public pub(String topicName, String username, String password)
        throws Exception {
            // Obtain a JNDI connection
            Properties env = new Properties( );
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "guest"); 
            env.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory"); 
            env.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:1099"); 
            env.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming");

            // ... specify the JNDI properties specific to the vendor

            InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext(env);


            // Look up a JMS connection factory
            TopicConnectionFactory conFactory =
            (TopicConnectionFactory)jndi.lookup("TopicConnectionFactory");

            // Create a JMS connection
            TopicConnection connection =
            conFactory.createTopicConnection(username,password);





            // Create two JMS session objects
            TopicSession pubSession =
            connection.createTopicSession(false,
                                          Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            TopicSession subSession =
            connection.createTopicSession(false,
                                          Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Look up a JMS topic
            Topic chatTopic = (Topic)jndi.lookup(topicName);

            // Create a JMS publisher and subscriber
            TopicPublisher publisher1 = 
                pubSession.createPublisher(chatTopic);
            TopicSubscriber subscriber = 
                subSession.createSubscriber(chatTopic);

            // Set a JMS message listener
            subscriber.setMessageListener(this);

            // Intialize the Chat application
            set(connection, pubSession, subSession, publisher1, username);

            // Start the JMS connection; allows messages to be delivered
            connection.start( );

        }
        /* Initialize the instance variables */
        public void set(TopicConnection con, TopicSession pubSess,
                        TopicSession subSess, TopicPublisher pub, 
                        String username) {
            this.connection = con;
            this.pubSession = pubSess;
            this.subSession = subSess;
            this.publisher = pub;
            this.username = username;
        }
        /* Receive message from topic subscriber */
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            try {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                String text = textMessage.getText( );
                System.out.println(text);
            } catch (JMSException jmse){ jmse.printStackTrace( ); }
        }
        /* Create and send message using topic publisher */
        protected void writeMessage(String text) throws JMSException {
            TextMessage message = pubSession.createTextMessage( );
            message.setText(username+" : "+text);
            publisher.publish(message);
        }
        /* Close the JMS connection */
        public void close( ) throws JMSException {
            connection.close( );
        }
        /* Run the Chat client */
        public static void main(String [] args){
            try{
                if (args.length!=3)
                    System.out.println("Topic or username missing");

                // args[0]=topicName; args[1]=username; args[2]=password
                pub chat = new pub(args[0],args[1],args[2]);

                // Read from command line
                BufferedReader commandLine = new 
                  java.io.BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                // Loop until the word "exit" is typed
                while(true){
                    String s = commandLine.readLine( );
                    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
                        chat.close( ); // close down connection
                        System.exit(0);// exit program
                    } else 
                        chat.writeMessage(s);
                }
            } catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace( ); }
        }
    }
    i do this ![enter image description here][1]
    and now i get this eroor 
    ![enter image description here][2]
    and i dont no what i do not ok i will be happy for help thanks!!


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c04o1.gif
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxCIU.gif
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) about how to make the questions. Also, change the question title.

Comment: Don't know if it is mentioned in the FAQ but I only read as far as.. *"hi i want.."*  ..before stopping.  Please add an upper case letter at the start of every sentence, as well as for the word 'I'.  This makes it easier to read.  You would not want to make it **harder to read,** would you?

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at chat.pub.main(pub.java:105)
```

It means you started the program without giving it arguments

Then at line 105

```
pub chat = new pub(args[0],args[1],args[2]);
```

you are accessing the 0th element of args when args is empty.

Rerun program and give parameters (3) as you need.

Edit:

In order to run provide arguments in Eclipse:

Run - >Run Configuration - > Select pub (Since you have already tried running it in eclipse) - > Select Arguments -> Under Program Argument specify the parameters delimited by space

[Pictorial View](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-jdk-ide-tutorials/362-how-send-command-line-arguments-eclipse.html)

Comment: hi thanks for help i edit my messeg after your help and i add photo  what worng after i do this  i wuld happy for help